# foreign key setup in sqlalchemy

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I want to set up a many to one relationship between table "stock_data" and "adv_dec" table on column Date. Here's my models.py file:

```
    from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Float, Date, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

Base = declarative_base()


class StockData(Base):
    """ Data model for stock data insertion """
    __tablename__ = "stock_data"
    id = Column(Integer,
                primary_key=True,
                nullable=False,
                autoincrement=True)
    Stock_name = Column("Stock_name", String(100),
                        nullable=False)
    Date = Column("Date", Date, nullable=False)
    Open = Column("Open", Float, nullable=False)
    High = Column("High", Float, nullable=False)
    Low = Column("Low", Float, nullable=False)
    Close = Column("Close", Float, nullable=False)
    Del_volume = Column("Del_volume", Integer, nullable=False)
    Trade_volume = Column("Trade_volume", Integer, nullable=False)
    adv_dec = relationship("AdvDec", cascade="all,delete", backref="stock_data")


class AdvDec(Base):
    """ data model for advance decline numbers """
    __tablename__ = "adv_dec"
    Date = Column("Date", Date, ForeignKey(StockData.Date), primary_key=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    Advance = Column("Advance", Integer, nullable=False)
    Decline = Column("Decline", Integer, nullable=False)
```

This is the error I get when I create all tables by:
calling `Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)`

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidForeignKey) there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "stock_data"

[SQL: 
CREATE TABLE adv_dec (
    "Date" DATE NOT NULL, 
    "Advance" INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    "Decline" INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY ("Date"), 
    UNIQUE ("Date"), 
    FOREIGN KEY("Date") REFERENCES stock_data ("Date")
)
]
```

Does this mean that Date column in "stock_data" has to be unique as well? As I want to set up many to one from "stock_data" to "adv_dec", that cannot be unique for me. Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong? I want the stock_data to be created first followed by adv_dec for the foreign key to work.

Thanks a lot,
Arnab

Comment: yes, that I understand, foreign key must be unique if primary key, but still it can be many to one relationship, I don't get why it must be one to one

Comment: My bad, I must have been asleep when commenting.  The [m21 docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-one) couple using backref with the FK in the parent table, so maybe `adv_dec_id = sa.Column(sa.Date, sa.ForeignKey('adv_dec.Date')` in `StockData` and remove the `ForeignKey` from `AdvDec.Date`?